# Media Framework not importing items

Tags: frameworks, sitecore, media, brightcove

We have media framework Brightcove edition configured and pulling in content for the most part.

We have run into an issue where some items with special characters or non-English language characters do not get imported because of the item name restrictions.

Is there a way to cleanup or sanitize items for Media Framework exports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Brightcove API to go [through your videos](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/references/reference.html#Video_Read) and [update them](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/references/reference.html#Video_Write) with removing of special characters.

Or another option: override part of Media Framework that is responsible for importing of items and include there logic of renaming. It also should work as name is not used as identifier for Brightcove videos.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use video ids instead of video names when creating the video items?

Comment: I think you should include your processor before or instead <processor type="Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaSyncImport.MediaSyncItemImport.CreateItem, Sitecore.MediaFramework" /> in mediaFramework.mediaSyncItemImport pipeline and correct name of item.